# Сжатие mdb базы

Tags: база-данных, access, opensource, mdb

Здравствуйте!

В Microsoft Acccess есть такая чудесная функция как "Сжать и восстановить базу данных" которая в моём случае делает из 2гб базы базу на 14 мегабайт.

Но увы нет столько лицензий на то что бы расставить Office по всем рабочим местам.

Существуют ли фри-аналоги для работы с .mdb которые могут выполнить схожую операцию?

Answer (score 0):

Такое разрастание базы говорит об ошибках в проектировании, не учитывающих эту особенность. Если в приложении используются временные таблицы с многочисленными удалениями-вставками, то такого рода таблицы нужно хранить в отдельном файле и заменять его на "оригинальный" при каждом запуске программы.
Если же переделать нет возможности, поставьте беспланый рантайм Акцесса и сжимайте командой типа

```
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office16\msaccess.exe" "C:\File.accdb" /compact
```

Comment: Просто открывается окно загрузки и сразу закрывается. Ч.я.д.н.т.? Кстати нигде не могу найти список команд почему то.

Comment: Ой оказывается надо msaccess.exe "1.mdb" /compact

Comment: Да, ключ после имени файла, поправил